# Specifying the location of mocha.opts when running mocha with nyc?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, istanbul, nyc

Is it possible to specify the location of `mocha.opts` when running `nyc mocha`?  I'd like to have it in the root project folder.  I tried this in my npm script:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "nyc mocha --config ./mocha.opts"
},
```

That did not work.  I did get a test case working for the setup described [here](http://azimi.me/2016/09/30/nyc-mocha-typescript.1.html) however, with `mocha.opts` in the `test` directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mocha --opts <path_to_opts_file>
```